# How can use razor Comment on JavaScript block/

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

When I create a razor comment block into a script block in cshtml file, the javascript intelisense gives me error.
How we can solve this?
hint: I use VisualStudio 2012 and Resharper 7.1.2

I know that we can use nested comment like below code ( razor comment and a javascript comment outer of that)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //@*
    var something = "bla bla";
    //*@
    var other = "something else";
</script>
```

it must work properly but there are two problem
1- intelisense gets me error yet
2- Since razor ignore spaces, the rest of my codes after closing comment symbol ( *@ )

Edit1:

other things that I tried was:

```
/*@*
var something = "bla bla";
*@*/
var other = "something else";
```

and

```
/*@*
var something = "bla bla";
*@*/
var other = "something else";
```

. but they have some problem too.

Comment: Why not just use JavaScript comment syntax? Also why are you using inline JavaScript?

Comment: Can you paste some code? Comments should not affect this.

Comment: Why do you want comment? If needed you can do it with conditional statement like if :)

Comment: @Murali can you get me more details?

Comment: @JamesSouth because I dont want to send my comments to client.

Comment: @DarrenDavies I update my post and add some snippet see that

Comment: @OmidShariati I added my answer. Let will it be helpful

Comment: @OmidShariati Then stick them just before the script block. Either way you shouldn't have JavaScript nested in Razor script. It's a maintenance nightmare. Move your script to a separate file where it belongs and your problem will go away.

Comment: @JamesSouth is absolutely correct.

Comment: thanks everybody I know your warning about using inline javascript. but I only want to know how can solve this question even if it's a bad practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find my answer that is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*@*
var something = "bla bla";
*@//*/
var other = "something else";
</script>
```

It will be rendered as

```
/*//*/
var other = "something else";
```

visual studio intelisense and resharper works properly!!!

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your problem, you want to define a javascript variable based on some condition.

If that is true, you can try the below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@if (Model.UserCanSee)
{

    <text>
        var uiEnabled=true;         
    </text>
}
else{

    <text>
        var uiDisabled=true;         
    </text>
}
</script>
```

Comment: thats not only about javascript variables. its about inline javascript on razor pages. ( any javascript code )